# LogCat is unable to show exceptions

Tags: android, logcat

Suppose I have this piece of code:

```
public class Class1 extends Activity
{
   private int [] array;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        someFunction(array.length); <--- NullPointerException
   }
}
```

Normally the LogCat in eclipse tells me what the exception is, and where is the line that is causing trouble, but for an unknown reason, it does not anymore. Instead, it just throw the following error :

```
12-30 22:27:06.650: E/Trace(28894): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-30 22:27:06.670: W/dalvikvm(28894): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
```

How can I solve this? I´ve seen many posts speaking of this problem, but I haven´t been able to solve the issue. Thanx.

Comment: where you are initializing `array` Array?

Comment: That is exactly the point, I made that code on purpose. Eclipse was able to tell me where the exception is, but not anymore.

Comment: please add `array = {1,2,3};` before `someFunction(array.length);` line then try to run

Comment: You are not understanding the trouble here. The trouble is that Eclipse is not able to tell me where the exception is, the trouble is not the app, is in the editor. Sorry if I didn´t make myself clear.

Comment: Instead of showing the errors that I posted, eclipse should show where the exception is, that is not happening and that is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the only way to solve the issue, was shutting down eclipse and starting again. I dont know why this happens, but restarting fixed it.